# If an If statement contains a lot of method calls, should you just give those method calls a "variable name"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, instead of writing,

1.

```
// If the square in front of piece is not occupied then highlight the square  

if($(`#${currentHighlightedPiece.currentSquareLetter}${currentHighlightedPiece.currentSquareNumber-1}`).children().length === 0){
// ...
};
```

Would I be better off writing,

2.

```
var forwardOneOccupantSize = $(`#${currentHighlightedPiece.currentSquare[0]}${currentHighlightedPiece.currentSquare[1]-1}`).children().length;

// If the square in front of piece is not occupied then highlight the square  

if(forwardOneOccupantSize === 0){
    // do stuff
}
```

?

2. Would be more "descriptive" but contains more lines of code, to achieve the same goal.

Comment: In case you don't need to recalculate that - yes, it would be much better to save the value in a variable. In case the value might change - use a function instead.

Comment: There's no coding benefit from changing this.  You might find it easier to maintain later and it can be clearer.  If you're using the same code more than once, then yes as it means you only have to set it one place so is less prone to errors on the subsequent settings and won't have to re-calculate each time.   If you're using it once, then there's no benefit.

Comment: The issue here surely isn't the number of method calls (there's only one, `.children()`), but the length of variable names and property names. Shorten them and the expression will be far more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided to write it as an answer to give more information :)

1. In case you don't need to recalculate that - yes, it would be much better to save the value in a variable. Your code would be much more readable and other programmers (and even you) will need less time to understand/change/bugfix this code in the future.
2. In case the value might change (which is pretty common when you look at element's dimensions/positions) - it would be much better to use a function for that.

```
function checkSpecificContainerNumberOfChildren() {
    return $(`#${currentHighlightedPiece.currentSquareLetter}${currentHighlightedPiece.currentSquareNumber-1}`).children().length === 0;

}

if(checkSpecificContainerNumberOfChildren()){
    // ...
};
```

Since you talk about the DOM, which might change over time - it is better to use a function for that call.

Comment: @Jonasw, indeed - another option here

Answer (score 0):

You can put your check inside an if statement if you only need this check one time (if you do not need to recalculate it).

A variable is more pretty if you need the results many time (like in a loop). However, you should be careful if the result of the function can change: if you put the result in a variable, the value of the variable is the value of the function when you call the function. You should don't do it if you track a position for example!

Finally, you should declare a constant (const in your code) than a variable (var) which take more place in the computer, if you use the second solution.